# Two sql tables referencing each other with nullable fields: pitfall?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

In the current system, we track equipment for an organization. A different org wants to also use the system, so we designed a small subset area for them to store their equipment (before they used an excel document). This organization's data is differently structured than the first org.

Now both organizations are wanting the ability to convert items to the other org, and then be able to transfer ownership back and forth.

I added a nullable FK to both the equipment tables referencing the other item. So in practice, when it is converted over, it will point to the equivalent item on the other side, and vice versa. 1:0,1 style.

A coworker mentioned that this would cause problems, but I couldn't find any issues I could think of outside of a circular relationship type of problem? Since both FK fields are nullable, there wouldn't be a chicken-egg issue, would there? Or should I change it to a junction table to house this relationship.

Eventually, once most data has been 'converted', we plan on consolidating down to just 1 table. The below code is just the table layout. Would the issue be creating the table initially in the event we start up a new database? I added the FK's in an alter table statement, the tables themselves have already been created. Not every piece of equipment will be converted over.

Why don't I just write something up to convert table b data to table a? because the data they have is very messy and they do not track required things that table a has. Hence why I made a function on the application to help them convert items over.

```
    create table table1 (
      column1 int primary key not null,
      ...
      columnX int null,
          
        );
    
    create table table2 (
      column1 int primary key not null,
      ...
      columnX int null
   );

   alter table... constraint fk1
            foreign key (columnX)
            references table2 (column1)

   alter table... constraint fk2
        foreign key (columnX)
        references table1 (column1)
```

Comment: Why not just add a column that indicates which organization "owns" the row?  Then you can use a view for each organization.

Comment: That is the ultimate plan for once all the data is consolidated down to 1 table. When we first developed the application, it was meant just for org A. But management bought into org B using it to just store their equipment (instead of just using an excel document). Now they want extra features, like transferring the item over to org A for them to use, but the MVC views we use do not match up with org B's data currently. That is why I am trying to have the convert function to help them match up/fix data, and link the 2 items together

Comment: I know it is a trash setup overall. When I took on the task of getting their equipment in just to store/update their fields, it was fine in it's own table separate from everything else. But now they want more integration into the app. A lot of the fields of equipment that org A requires, org B does not care about and didn't/doesn't store.

They do want to be able to give ownership of their equipment (and vice versa) to the other org, and have data syncing (once the link is made, updates in org B will happen in org A's table as well)

Comment: What database are you using or planing?

Comment: we are using microsoft sql server.